# Why is the menu not displayed properly?

Tags: android, android-layout

The xml code of my drawer_menu

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:showIn="navigation_view">

<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item android:id="@+id/sun"
        android:title="Sun"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/moon"
        android:title="Moon"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/planets"
        android:title="Planets"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/stars"
        android:title="Stars"/>
</group>
<item android:title="Communicate">
    <menu>
        <item android:id="@+id/nav_sun"
            android:title="Sun"/>
    </menu>
</item>
```

[image: Menu look like]

Menu looks like 
How can I fix it?

My dependecies

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

I think I need something to my dependencies. But in the Net I didnt find nothing related to androidx

Comment: Can you share your xml code?

Comment: xml code in the question I did nothing in main_activity with drawer_activity

Answer (score 0):

Reason is **`tools:showIn="navigation_view"`**. remove it from xml. It's a bug of android studio.

Comment: Then It will look like menu with 3 dots in right corner but I need a sliding menu

Comment: It's a known bug. Why you depend on the **preview**?. It's working as expected when you run the application in an emulator or phone.